# C++ null value and this pointer

Tags: c++, this

I'm a newbie in C++, trying to study C++. I have a block of code in Java like this:

```
public List<String> getDiagnosticTroubleCode() {
    if (diagnosticTroubleCode == null) {
        diagnosticTroubleCode = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    return this.diagnosticTroubleCode;
}
```

How can I compare the `disgnosticTroubleCode` with `null` value? and set it as a new `List`. I already override the `std::list` to make it use like `List` in Java. And then I want to return the `diagnosticTroubleCode` field within the object `this`. I hope that you guys can help me with this. Trying to study about `this` pointer and `null`.

Here is my header in C++ :

```
class RUNTIME_EXPORTS DiagnosticTroubleCode {
            protected:
                List diagnosticTroubleCode;
            public:
                List getDiagnosticTroubleCode();
            };
```

Comment: you can't assign Java's null to an object in c++, you have to switch to pointers, and assign nullptr at most

Comment: The first block of code is in Java.

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia can you give me an answer that can best help me for this situation.

Comment: There is no such thing as a null value, only a null pointer.

Comment: @Frontear yeah, thanks. Can you give me an answer to this situation?

Comment: it's not that easy to explain what is a pointer, what's the difference to an object, how they behave differently and so on, you should check some resources on the web about C++ pointers

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Okay, thanks, mate.

Comment: Sure, just switch to pointers. I don't recommend this being your approach though. Not everything can be so smoothly translate into c++ from a language like java. Try to think of a better way to handle it, start with why you even except this list to be null, and if it really needs to be null

Comment: C++ isn't broken like Java. You don't have an actual problem to solve. You just need to remove the test against `null`, because your `List<T>` object will never be `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code appears to desire only instantiating `diagnosticTroubleCode` on first use. Frankly, I find that somewhat odd, since an instance of an otherwise-empty `std::list<std::string>` would be rather benign. Regardless, this is one way to do that.

```
class DiagnosticTroubleCode 
{
protected:
    std::unique_ptr<std::list<std::string>> diagnosticTroubleCode;

public:
    std::list<std::string>& getDiagnosticTroubleCode()
    {
        if (!diagnosticTroubleCode)
            diagnosticTroubleCode = std::make_unique<std::list<std::string>>();
        return *diagnosticTroubleCode;
    }
};
```

Note that the member `getDiagnosticTroubleCode` will return a reference to the new (or existing) instantiated list. If you decide to forego latent instantiation (I recommend doing so), the code becomes considerably simpler:

```
class DiagnosticTroubleCode 
{
protected:
    std::list<std::string> diagnosticTroubleCode;

public:
    std::list<std::string>& getDiagnosticTroubleCode()
    {
        return diagnosticTroubleCode;
    }
};
```

If the latter is possible (and frankly, I cannot see how it isn't), pursue that first. IN both cases above the member is returned by reference, not value or address. This would most-closely resemble what you're probably familiar with.

Best of luck.

Comment: What will happen if you return a reference? I don't figure out how different between return the reference and the variable itself?

Comment: @NguyễnĐứcTâm The code above *does* return a reference, so I don't understand your question.

Comment: `std::list<std::string>& getDiagnosticTroubleCode()` is it return a reference? sorry, i'm newbie in C++.

Comment: Currently, I think that `std::list<std::string>& getDiagnosticTroubleCode()` and `std::list<std::string> getDiagnosticTroubleCode()` are different. So that why I said so.Sorry for my bad understanding, but still don't get it.

Comment: @NguyễnĐứcTâm Clearly they're different. That `&` on the return type indicates a reference-to. Without it, the result is a value-of . Honestly I'm not all that thrilled about this example, since Java references, including their management are more akin to shared-pointers than C++ references, but it seems suitable for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks mate. Really appreciated spending your time explaining this for me.

Answer (score 2):

I remember in Java everything are pointers. So in Java `diagnosticTroubleCode == null` is essentially comparing `diagnosticTroubleCode` with a null pointer. In C++ we do not have null, we have `NULL` or `nullptr`. In C++ an object cannot really be null because it is not. An object takes up a block of memory when it gets constructed, so it can never be null. So try to familiarize yourself with pointers and use that in your advantage.

On the matter of `this`. If you want to return a member variable, you don't really need to write `return this.variable`, you can simply return the variable by writing `return variable`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that everything in Java is pointers. `return variable` and `return this->variable` is there any difference?

Comment: `this` is simply a pointer pointing to the object itself. If you wanna return a member variable, you are essentially accessing the member variable. If you wanna access a member variable within the scope of the class, there is really no need to use `this`. Member variables can be accessed directly by member functions.

Comment: But to answer your question. When in the scope of the class, `return variable` and `return this->variable` have no difference.

Answer (score 1):

The difference here is that in Java all complex structure declarations are really declarations of *references* to such structures. In C++, that's the equivalent of saying `List& foo` or `List* foo`. C/C++ declarations are true instances, which is one of the reasons why there can be a bit of complexity with memory management, but it comes with the benefit of information integrity: For example, when you pass a Java `List<String>` as an argument of a method and change the contents of that argument, it's changed in the calling scope. C/C++, on the other hand, will *copy* the argument regardless of object complexity, and when the function/method returns, the one passed as an argument is otherwise preserved.

Your C++ class example should look something like this:

```
#include <list>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class RUNTIME_EXPORTS DiagnosticTroubleCode {
  protected:
    list<string>* diagnosticTroubleCode{nullptr};
  public:
    list<string>* getDiagnosticTroubleCode();
};

list<string>* DiagnosticTroubleCode::getDiagnosticTroubleCode(){
  if (diagnosticTroubleCode == nullptr) {
        diagnosticTroubleCode = new List<string>();
    }
    return diagnosticTroubleCode;
}
```

There are better implementations that don't require returning a pointer or reference, but they impose additional design requirements (such as what the adding a trouble-code mechanism should be).

Comment: It should be a `std::unique_ptr`, not a raw pointer. Implementing this with a raw pointer would require implementation of the special member functions to correctly handle deletion of the pointer.

Comment: Agreed, but didn't want to introduce too many "new" concepts to a beginner in one answer.

Comment: That is why raw `new` should be introduced after `std::unique_ptr`. Your class is currently broken and leaks all its memory until everything is implemented correctly. OP will probably not realize the memory leaks because this is not a concern in Java.

Comment: I'm not arguing that my example implementation above is "good" (hell, I'd chew out any engineer on my team for writing such). But I'm not going to add to a discussion regarding Java's inherent object reference nature versus C++'s instantiative nature more information regarding memory management best-practices. OP's still trying to figure out the syntax of C++ and the significance of instances versus references; the answer is only intended to point at that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Function

class DiagnosticTroubleCode 
{
protected:
    std::unique_ptr<std::list<std::string>> diagnosticTroubleCode;

public:
    std::list<std::string>& getDiagnosticTroubleCode()
    {
        if (!diagnosticTroubleCode)
            diagnosticTroubleCode = std::make_unique<std::list<std::string>>();
        return *diagnosticTroubleCode;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

My .cpp file :

```
shared_ptr<List> DiagnosticTroubleCodes::getDiagnosticTroubleCodes()
            {
                if (this->diagnosticTroubleCodes == nullptr) {
                    this->diagnosticTroubleCodes = make_shared<List>();
                }
                return diagnosticTroubleCodes;
            }
```

And My header file:

```
class RUNTIME_EXPORTS DiagnosticTroubleCodes {
            protected:
                shared_ptr<List> diagnosticTroubleCodes;
            public:
                shared_ptr<List> getDiagnosticTroubleCodes();
            };
```

I come up with this solution.

Comment: Your function has undefined behavior, because it doesn't actually return what you claim it returns. (I think you just forgot the `return` statement.) And as discussed in other questions, this is unlikely to be a good C++ design. You should prefer to use `List` directly (then it can never be `null`) or if you have a good reason to `std::unique_ptr`. `std::shared_ptr` has bad runtime performance and some subtle pitfalls that you will run into sooner or later. It should only be used if you don't know who will be responsible for destroying the `List`.

Comment: Also note that if you now copy a `DiagnosticTroubleCodes` instance, both copies may refer to *the same or to different* `List` instances. Whether or not will depend on whether `getDiagnosticTroubleCodes` is called before the copy is made or not. Are you sure that is what you want?

Comment: I need to check if it null or not so I change to use a smart pointer, can you edit my answer to make it good design in C++, I don't have much experience in design in C++ style.

Comment: In C++ good design means that you don't let things be `null` if that is not a valid state with different semantics from other states. It seems to me that you want `diagnosticTroubleCodes` to not be `null` whenever you access it (through `getDiagnosticTroubleCodes`). If that is the case, you don't need any (smart or raw) pointers, just follow @WhozCraig's second example (chance `std::list<string`> to `List`) and you don't ever need to check for `null`, because it can't be `null`. It will be initialized automatically with an instance of `List` when a `DiagnosticTroubleCodes` instance is created.